# How to join collections in Magento?

Tags: magento, join, collections, grid

I am trying to join a custom collection with products to show the product name (not just the id) in the admin grid widget. So far i can't find the correct syntax.

I am able to retrieve the products with the product name by the following:

> Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');

and i can retrieve my custom collection with:

> Mage::getResourceModel('xyz_mymodule/model_collection');

How do i join the two so that the module collection is the primary collection and the id as returned by $model->getId() is still the id of my custom collection?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here you have a working example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('order_item'=> 'sales_flat_order_item'), 'order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id', array('order_item.sku'));
```

Comment: That worked just as i needed once i put my tables in. I used:

Comment: $collection->getSelect()->join( array('product'=> 'catalog_product_flat_1'), 
              'product.entity_id = main_table.product_fk',
           array('*',
              "product_name" => "product.name",
              "container_name" => "main_table.name",
              )
            );

Comment: Hard-coding table names in?  Seems like that would break in situations where there is a prefix utilized.  Should use Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order') to take advantage of any community / local overrides as well as handle prefixes.

Comment: @BetoCastillo you missed the fact that sometimes magento's `join` or `joinTable` functions reduces the number of records than the normal query, like this code `$collection->joinTable(
         array('sfoi' => 'sales/order_item'), 'product_id = entity_id',
         array(
          'last_sold_date' => 'MAX(sfoi.created_at)',
          'total_qty_sold' => 'SUM(sfoi.qty_ordered)'
         )
        );
        $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');`, how to resolve this ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, feel free to edit the answer :D @VickyDev

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick correction I had to add quotes on the table name: 
array('order_item'=> **'sales_flat_order_item'**), 
Also getSelect() is not necessary as the third argument is the attribute list.
Final argument specifies the type of join you would like to use.

My version looked like this:

---

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$collection->join(array('order'=> 'sales/order'),'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id', array('po_number'=>'po_number', 'imi_customer_email' =>'imi_customer_email'), null,'left');
$this->setCollection($collection);`
```

Comment: Thanks, i missed those quotes :)