# Join two tables and put results in grid magento 1.9.x

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm working on a custom module with a flat table containing product's sku in it. I'd like to show in a grid sku and name taken from catalog/product and other info taken by my own table;
in Grid.php I have:

```
 protected function _prepareCollection() 
        {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('hf/hfdistr')->getCollection();

            $this->setCollection($collection);

            return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
```

How can take product name from catalog/product and merge it with my table additional info? Any help appreciated. (Magento 1.9.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

You can join them like this

```
$products = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/model')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    array(
      'cp'=> $products
    ),
    'cp.sku = main_table.sku',
    array(
      'cp.sku','cp.other_attribute_other',
      'cp.other_attribute_to_select'
    ));
```

[How to join collections in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237348/how-to-join-collections-in-magento)
Not tested! :D

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I was not able to make it work;  in particular I can't get product name from catalog/product...  Could you help me on this ? I'd like to have sku and product name taken from catalog/product and matched with product sku taken from my table and then added and showed in grid with a,b,c details taken from  my table

Comment: This is my function: 
protected function _prepareCollection() 
    {
$products = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
$collection = Mage::getModel('hf/hfdistr')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('cp'=> $products), 'cp.sku = main_table.sku', array('cp.sku','cp.name'));
 $this->setCollection($collection);


        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
If I put cp.sku only work as expected, while if I add cp.name an exception is printed (column name not found)... Thank you for your time...

Comment: On that case, it would be better if you refer to this :
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29859/how-to-join-custom-table-with-product-collection

Comment: Thank you for the advice...
I found this very helpful:[link](https://plugin.company/blog/join-eav-attribute-flat-table-collection-magento/)